# Field number takes the commas and points as part of the Length

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a problem in oracle forms, I have in the database a field number (10) this field in forms has a mask 99,999,999. The field is counting dots and commas as part of the Length. There is some way that field only counts the numbers. The table field is ORD_DIST NUMBER (10)
In the image are the properties in forms.

[image: Image of properties]

Comment: Your mask is only 8 numeric digits? If adding two nines to the mask makes no difference, can you set highest allowed value to 99999999, or indeed 9999999999, maybe with length increased to match if necessary? (I don't use Forms so just guessing *8-)

Answer (score 0):

NUMBER(10) in database means, that your number has 10 digits. Dots and commas are not counted, because they are only used for display representation of the number.
Format mask and maximum length in forms define number field from user point of view. That means including displayed commas, dots or spaces.
Your field enables only 8 digits.